# Why does "cin" not wοrk again after EOF?

Tags: c++

Today our Data Structure class asked us to implement Horner's Rule. I made it at last, but there is a small bug that upsets me very much. I use a `while` loop to read and save the coefficients of the polynomial, and I used another `cin` to read the value of the variable called `x`. The thing is, after I reach EOF to terminate reading the coefficients, the following `cin` part that reads the variable `x` does not execute. This puzzles me very much.

```
while(std::cin>>n){
    coeff.append(n);
}
std::cout<<"Now enter the value";
std::cin>>x;
```

The program is correct in syntax, but it just skips the second `cin` which reads the variable `x`.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but note that `std::cin` is an object. It doesn't do anything on its own. It gets passed as data to various functions, such as `operator>>`, and it's those functions that do the work. So this question is more accurately phrased as "why doesn't the stream extractor work when I pressed EOF to terminate a previous input operation".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have terminated the stream, nothing more is added to it and there is nothing more to read.

You need a different "end of coefficients" marker.

The simplest way is to require all coefficients to be entered on one line:

```
std::string line;
if (std::getline(std::cin, line))
{
    std::istringstream is(line);
    int n = 0; // or whatever type you're using.
    while (is >> n)
    {
        coeff.append(n);
    }
    std::cout << "Enter the value: ";
    std::cin >> x;

    // Evaluation code here.
}
else
{
    // Possibly handle error
}
```

Other options include defining a "magic" coeffient as the marker, or take some invalid (i.e. non-numeric) input and then `clear()` the stream before continuing.